# Making @IndexedEmbedded Entity as Read Only relationship in Hibernate Search

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-search

Below are the mappings of two of our entities. They contain ManyToOne relationship.

**Entity A:**

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = First.class)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "seq", referencedColumnName = "seq", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "addrSeq", referencedColumnName = "addrSeq", insertable = false, updatable = false) })
    @IndexedEmbedded 
    private Second second;


public Second getSecond() {
            return second;
        }
    
        public void setSecond(Second second) {
            this.second= second;
        }
```

**Entity B:**

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="second", targetEntity = First.class)
    @ContainedIn
    private Set<First> first;
```

**JPA Details:**
Using `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository`'s save() method to persist the data.

as:
**Repo Class:**

```
public interface FirstRepository extends JpaRepository<First, FirstID>{}
```

Then in the controller we first set.. all data setters for First entity and then:

```
repository.save(first);
```

Now the issue is, when ever try to persist First entity, hibernate tries to persist Second entity and as it finds the object blank it throws below error for the second entity:

> object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient
> instance before flushing

Is it possible to have a readonly relationships just for the Hibernate Search(Elastic Indexing) purpose between the First and Second entities.
As I just need the indexed data from second entity in the first one on my Elastic indexes and will never add/update/delete the Second entity while doing these operations on the First. Further we are using JPA for persisting the First entity.

Also, we are not indexing the Second entity on Elastic. But it does contain @Field Annotated fields and the fields are getting embedded on the parent one in Indexes(Which is working fine).

Also, If I provide data to the Second entity inside the First entity at runtime before persisting the First one, it works. But its not picking up the relationship automatically at the time of persistence.

**Few Things that I've already tried:**

1. Playing with Cascade and Fetch type attributes.
2. Using @Transient on `@IndexedEmbedded private Second second;`, then did not face the issue, but data was not available on the Index for second entity.

Comment: "object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing" => This typically indicates there's something wrong in your entity when you persist it. This is probably not related to your mapping, but to which getters/setters you are calling. Could you clarify this: "But its not picking up the relationship automatically at the time of persistence"?

Comment: @yrodiere, I've updated the question with my getter/setters. Please see if these are not correct or something is needed more for doing, what I'm trying to.

Further by "But its not picking up the relationship automatically at the time of persistence" I meant, when I inspect the First entity in debug, the second entity is fully empty. Which I think is fine, and may be hibernate creates this relationship at the time of persisiting

Comment: The implementation of getters/setters is not important, I fully expected them to be implemented that way. What's important is the code that calls these setters and calls `entityManager.persist()`.

Comment: @yrodiere, I've updated the answer with  the JPA repo we are using. We are directly using the save() method of "org.springframework.data.jpa.repository" for persisiting. Is there any specific area that I should look into or share with you, so you can have a clearer picture on this. Please share the directions for me.
Further, I am not calling any setters for second entity before persisiting the parent First entity(is this what you meant by "What's important is the code that calls these setters ")

Answer (score 0):

Bi-directional JPA associations have an "owner" side and a "non-owner" side. You can generally identify the "non-owner" side by the "mappedBy" attribute in your mapping (e.g. `@OneToMany(mappedBy = ...)`).

Here, `First` is the owner, `Second` is on the non-owner side.

What does it mean to be the "owner"? Roughly speaking, it means the `First` table will contain a column with a foreign key pointing to the `Second` table.

Thus, when you create a `First`, if you populate its association to `Second`, the `Second` must already exist in the database. Otherwise the insertion of the row in the `First` table will fail, because a foreign key cannot point to an ID that doesn't exist.

Thus, your code should call `save(second)`, and only then it should call `save(first)`. That will allow you to persist your two entities without any failure.

You should also take care of populating both sides of the association.

Then Hibernate Search will correctly index your entity.

Comment: thank u, I do not have all the data of second when am saving first, just the key part is available. will have to fetch the full data from DB. I believed this should have worked auto, as I have ```@indexed``` and ```@contained in``` relation. And plz explain "Thus, when you create a First, if you populate its association to Second," .  Going by ur answer I believe there is no way we can have a read-only kinda relationships, for use with respect to ES indexes.